# How to scroll a layout that contains 2 listviews and a textview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

In my activity page ,there is a layout which contains one listview at top(listview1),below listview1 ,there is a textrview and below this testview,second listview  is placed. I want to scroll the full layout.

Below is the sample code

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrol1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstMore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false" android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Learn More"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@id/lstMore"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstMoreBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_below="@id/textView2" android:divider="@null" android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It would be easier two answer if you gave more information. What does your code do, what happens, what do you see, etc...

Comment: by placing the above code,the main scrollview is not showing.Both listview1,listview2 scroll's are also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it's not possible to multiple ListViews in a ScrollView. You try to place two scrollable widgets in another scrollable widget.

What you should do is inflate different layouts in your list adapter and have a single ListView without the ScrollView.

Comment: Finally i got the solution..Just create a layout and inside that place the above code.And scrollview height should be some pixel and not wrapcontent/fill parent.By doing this ,you will get the full scrollview for that layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple listview in a scroll bar.
Use nestedscrollbar true in API 21 and above.Write this in your listview :      **'android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"'**

It will work definitly